# How to execute a SD Event on Notification Arrive

Tags: notifications, genexus, genexus-sd

The following code works fine for receiving a messages on a SD Device and executing an event when the end user taps on the notification.

```
&ApplicationIdCharacter = 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx'
&TheNotification.Text.DefaultText  = "Notification Provider API"
&TheNotification.Actions.DefaultAction.Event.Name = "Insert_Msg" 
&TheNotification.Appearance.Icon.Small = !"GX15IconKB"
&TheNotificationDelivery.Expiration = 3000 
&TheNotificationDelivery.Priority   = PushNotificationPriority.Normal
&TheNotificationConfiguration.ApplicationId = &ApplicationIdCharacter
&DeviceToken = 'xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'
GeneXus.Common.Notifications.SendNotification(&TheNotificationConfiguration,&DeviceToken,&TheNotification,&TheNotificationDelivery,&OutMessages,&IsSuccessful)
```

But I can´t find any example for doing this without user intervention.

On previous versions there was a parameter

```
&GXPushNotification.Event.Execution = EventExecution.OnNotificationArrive
```

Is it supported on GX 15?

Thanks,
Rogelio Arosemena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rogelio,

If you want to fire an Event without user intervention, then use the API:

GeneXus.Common.Notifications.SendEvent(..)

SendNotification is for sending Text Messages that requires user intervention to fire Events (by opening the Notification)

If you need Text and Event, then Send both (SendEvent & SendNotification)